# Can i get my variable out the foreach loop ? and send it with response along with the all users Data

Tags: php, distance

1. **Is it possible that I get both user details and distance along with users details**
2. **I want all the users details which I get in $data variable along with the $distance**
3. **both variables should be on the response.**

   ```
    public function getProfessionalByCityLatLon(Request $request)
        {
         $data = DB::table('profiles')
          ->leftJoin('cities','profiles.city','=','cities.id')
          ->leftJoin('users', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
          ->where('cities.name', '=', $request->select_city)                        
          ->get();

            foreach($data as $data1){
                $longitude1 = 23.6676092; // i will get it later from $request 
                $latitude1 = 86.0490814; // Same with this also
                $longitude2 = $data1->longitude;
                $latitude2 = $data1->latitude;

                $unit = 'kilometers';
                $theta = $longitude1 - $longitude2; 
                $distance = (sin(deg2rad($latitude1)) * sin(deg2rad($latitude2))) + (cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta))); 
                $distance = acos($distance); 
                $distance = rad2deg($distance); 
                $distance = $distance * 60 * 1.1515; 
                switch($unit) { 
                    case 'miles': 
                    break; 
                    case 'kilometers' : 
                    $distance = $distance * 1.609344;
                    $distance = $distance * 1000;  

                } 
                $profDistance = (round($distance, 2));

            }
            $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'distance' => $profDistance,
                'user' => $data,
                'message' => 'City retrieved successfully.',
            ];

            Log::info($response);
            return response()->json($response, 200);
        }
   ```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. What should be in `$profDistance` when there's more than one record in the DB?

Comment: $profDistance is for the calculated distance.
We are getting two variables (coordinates from the request) and two from DB. and after calculating the distance between them I want the result should be in one response along with the rest information of the user.

Comment: So there's only one record in the DB that matches? Then you don't need the `foreach` loop at all. Am I right in assuming this is Laravel/Eloquent? Just use `first()` instead of `get()` on the query. You'll get a single record back which you can then use to fill the rest of the data.

Comment: Thankyou @BenHillier I found the solution, Actually, First, I wanted all the records from DB where city name and category are according to parameters, Then I want to calculate the distance for each record coming from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, Actually, First, I wanted all the records from DB where city name and category are according to parameters, Then I want to calculate the distance for each record coming from the DB.

```
public function getProfessionalByCity($id, $currentLat, $currentLon)
    {
        Log::info('ye city select karne k baad on load calling ');
        // Log::info($id);
        $cityname = ucfirst($id);
            $newUser = DB::table('profiles')
                        ->leftJoin('cities','profiles.city','=','cities.id')
                        ->leftJoin('users', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                        ->where('cities.name', '=', $cityname)
                        ->get();
            // Log::info($newUser);
            $longitude1 = $currentLat;
            $latitude1 = $currentLon;
            foreach($newUser as $user)
            {
                $professionalAvatar = $user->avatar;
                $profileId = $user->id;
                $ProfessionalAvailable = $user->availability;
                $ProfessionalName = $user->full_name;
                $professionalProfession = $user->profession;
                $latitude2 =  $user->latitude;
                $longitude2 = $user->longitude;
                $unit = 'kilometers';
                $theta = $longitude1 - $longitude2; 
                $distance = (sin(deg2rad($latitude1)) * sin(deg2rad($latitude2))) + (cos(deg2rad($latitude1)) * cos(deg2rad($latitude2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta))); 
                $distance = acos($distance); 
                $distance = rad2deg($distance); 
                $distance = $distance * 60 * 1.1515; 
                switch($unit) { 
                    case 'miles': 
                    break; 
                    case 'kilometers' : 
                    $distance = $distance * 1.609344; 
                    // $distance = $distance * 1000;
                }
                $profId[] = $profileId ;
                $calculatedDistance[] = (round($distance, 2));
                $professName[] = $ProfessionalName;
                $profession[] = $professionalProfession;
                $availablity[] = $ProfessionalAvailable;
                $avatar[] = $professionalAvatar;
                // Log::info($calculatedDistance."ye h distance");
                // return (round($distance,2)); 
                
            }
            for($count = 0; $count < count($calculatedDistance); $count++)
                {
                   $data = array(
                    'Distance' => $calculatedDistance[$count],
                    'ProfessionalName' => $professName[$count],
                    'Profession' => $profession[$count],
                    'ID' => $profId[$count],
                    'Availablity' => $availablity[$count], 
                    'Avatar' => $avatar[$count],
                    
                   );
                   $calDistance[] =$data;
                } 
            $response = [
                'success' => true,
                'data' => $calDistance,
                'message' => 'City retrieved successfully.',
            ];
        // Log::info($response);
        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
```